# What are barriers to Genetic Programming with cyclic graphs

Tags: graphs, genetic-algorithms

Genetic programming uses either trees (in case of classical GP) or acyclic graphs (CGP and in a certain sense LGP), to represent evolved programs (phenotypes).

Is there any reason, why cyclic graphs aren't used?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one reason is that constraints (perhaps somewhat arbitrary ones) would have to be imposed on what it means to interpret a program represented in this fashion.

However, recent work with CGP has actually explored the addition of cycles:
[Recurrent CGP](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-10762-2_47)

Answer (score 0):

It's true that little research has been done on cyclic graph-based GP, but both:

- [Cartesian genetic programming](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-46239-2_9) by J.F. Miller, P. Thomson (2000).

  *The standard form of CGP is constrained to be acyclic, however the paper  describe the possibility of adjusting a parameter to allow cyclic individuals*.
- [Parallel distributed genetic programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.54.7666&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by R.Poli (1996)

specifically noted the ability of these representations to handle cyclic graphs.

There are also other less well-known papers (but anyway very interesting) that describe cyclic representations and various recombination operators:

- [JavaGenes: Evolving Graphs with Crossover](https://www.nas.nasa.gov/assets/pdf/techreports/2000/nas-00-018.pdf) by J. Lawton and T. Wipke (2004)
- [Algorithm evolution with Internal Reinforcement for Signal Understanding](http://www.astroteller.net/content/3-work/2-papers/6-algorithm-evolution-with-internal-reinforcement-for-signal-understanding/thesis.pdf) by Astro Teller (1998).

  *Take a look at the Neural Programming chapter which describes an inherently cyclic representation*.
- ...

Two problems with cyclic GP are:

- evaluation is often performed in an iterated [flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) fashion and is time consuming;
- memory requirements are greater because in tree-based individuals partial results aren't reused and so can be *discarded* after first use.

Approaches to speed up cyclic GP are described in [Strategies to Minimise the Total Run Time of Cyclic Graph Based Genetic Programming with GPUs](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~gmagoulas/p1379.pdf) by T.E. Lewis and G.D. Magoulas (2009).

As [noted by NietzscheanAI](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/79751/50003) there is a renewed interest about this topic.